# laravel .env file changed into .env.example when we push on github

Tags: github

Does  Github automatically change `.env` file to `.env.example` in Laravel?

Comment: Your `.env` file should _not_ be committed to git (may contain sensitive information) `.env` files are `.gitignore`'d by default. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: you should see your gitignore for it´s included in this file and only committed .env.example

Answer (score 3):

It is because your .env is added in `.gitignore` file by default by laravel. Also one shouldn't push .env on github for security purpose.

You can push on your private git repo. by removing `.env` from your `.gitignore` file, but again **it's bad practice**.